# How to get the fixed column width and to break the long table titles?

Tags: tables, formatting, column-width

I want to produce a table with a consistent format. However, since the lengths of my column names are different（a few of them are longer than the others), my table looks very weird...

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{appendix}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{plain}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
%\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn,booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
    \linespread{1.5}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\rk}{rk}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Card}{Card}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{Prob}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\cov}{cov}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\var}{var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var\,}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Post}{Post}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pre}{Pre}
\DeclareMathOperator{\post}{post}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pre}{pre}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mid}{Mid}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MID}{MID}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcommand{\tabnote}[1]{\vskip5pt{\justifying\noindent\small {\emph{Note:~}#1\par}}}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
     Country & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heavy } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Foreigner} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Female} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Parental Status} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Household Members } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Married} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Divorced/Seperated} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Single} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Widow} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Age} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Observations} \\
    \midrule
    Austria & 0.39  & 0.027 & 0.56  & 0.33  & 2     & 0.62  & 0.1   & 0.18  & 0.1   & 48    & 2941 \\
    Belgium & 0.37  & 0.066 & 0.52  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.7   & 0.08  & 0.14  & 0.09  & 51    & 2785 \\
    Bulgaria & 0.23  & 0.003 & 0.53  & 0.44  & 3     & 0.72  & 0.07  & 0.11  & 0.11  & 50    & 2827 \\
    Croatia & 0.36  & 0.005 & 0.57  & 0.46  & 3     & 0.64  & 0.05  & 0.21  & 0.11  & 47    & 1931 \\
    Cyprus & 0.29  & 0.057 & 0.52  & 0.54  & 3     & 0.68  & 0.05  & 0.22  & 0.05  & 45    & 1465 \\
    Czechia & 0.36  & 0.005 & 0.57  & 0.43  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.12  & 0.14  & 0.08  & 45    & 2925 \\
    Denmark & 0.6   & 0.02  & 0.51  & 0.33  & 2     & 0.64  & 0.1   & 0.16  & 0.09  & 53    & 2878 \\
    Estonia & 0.41  & 0.006 & 0.61  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.55  & 0.12  & 0.18  & 0.15  & 51    & 2815 \\
    Finland & 0.42  & 0.019 & 0.55  & 0.26  & 2     & 0.57  & 0.13  & 0.17  & 0.13  & 54    & 2870 \\
    France & 0.38  & 0.059 & 0.55  & 0.39  & 2     & 0.6   & 0.12  & 0.19  & 0.09  & 50    & 2905 \\
    Germany & 0.35  & 0.027 & 0.51  & 0.32  & 2     & 0.66  & 0.07  & 0.19  & 0.07  & 51    & 4304 \\
    Greece & 0.25  & 0.016 & 0.52  & 0.4   & 3     & 0.62  & 0.07  & 0.24  & 0.08  & 47    & 2918 \\
    Hungary & 0.21  & 0.004 & 0.59  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.64  & 0.11  & 0.13  & 0.13  & 49    & 2842 \\
    Ireland & 0.37  & 0.09  & 0.55  & 0.49  & 3     & 0.73  & 0.04  & 0.18  & 0.06  & 47    & 2771 \\
    Italy & 0.32  & 0.01  & 0.56  & 0.51  & 3     & 0.71  & 0.05  & 0.18  & 0.06  & 47    & 2842 \\
    Latvia & 0.41  & 0.006 & 0.57  & 0.49  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.11  & 0.16  & 0.07  & 44    & 2714 \\
    Lithuania & 0.31  & 0.001 & 0.59  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.53  & 0.13  & 0.19  & 0.15  & 48    & 2866 \\
    Luxembourg & 0.48  & 0.379 & 0.56  & 0.54  & 3     & 0.69  & 0.09  & 0.15  & 0.07  & 48    & 1414 \\
    Malta & 0.28  & 0.023 & 0.6   & 0.48  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.04  & 0.2   & 0.09  & 52    & 1419 \\
    Netherlands & 0.61  & 0.022 & 0.53  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.63  & 0.07  & 0.27  & 0.03  & 52    & 2864 \\
    Poland & 0.27  & 0.003 & 0.61  & 0.45  & 3     & 0.66  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.13  & 48    & 2793 \\
    Portugal & 0.21  & 0.016 & 0.56  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.62  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.12  & 49    & 2788 \\
    Romania & 0.2   & 0     & 0.5   & 0.42  & 3     & 0.73  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.1   & 47    & 2754 \\
    Slovakia & 0.3   & 0.008 & 0.58  & 0.5   & 3     & 0.69  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.11  & 48    & 2895 \\
    Slovenia & 0.34  & 0.012 & 0.57  & 0.46  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.04  & 0.17  & 0.11  & 51    & 2783 \\
    Spain & 0.29  & 0.06  & 0.52  & 0.44  & 3     & 0.68  & 0.06  & 0.19  & 0.07  & 48    & 2854 \\
    Sweden & 0.62  & 0.026 & 0.47  & 0.29  & 2     & 0.62  & 0.12  & 0.18  & 0.07  & 56    & 2890 \\
    United Kingdom & 0.39  & 0.091 & 0.54  & 0.38  & 2     & 0.55  & 0.09  & 0.26  & 0.1   & 50    & 3710 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

[image: My table using the code above]

Comment: Is writing columns headers in two lines an acceptable option? BTW, please make your document example minimal (let be preamble content only relevant to table) and compilable ...

Answer (score 1):

You may liked the following table design:

[image]

- For it I use the `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which loads packages of the same name)
- You should provide an MWE (MInimal Working example), i.e. a small but complete document, which preamble contain only to problem relevant information: page layout, used fonts, necessary packages and definition used in document body.
  -It seems, that for your document use quite old "template": you load obsolete package `subfigure` (now replaced by `subfig` but even better is to use `subcaption`.
- Some packages overwrite already loaded packages (lscape, `pdflscape`)
- Many packages are loaded several times.
- You really need to put some effort to clean up preamble ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
%\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\centering
    \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} l
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]
                      *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                           X[c, si={table-format=1.0}]
                      *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                           X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                           X[c, si={table-format=4.0}]
                      @{} },
            colsep=4pt,
            rowsep = 0pt,
            row{1} = {guard, m}
            }
    \toprule
Country     & Heavy & Foreigner 
                            &Female & {Parental\\ Status} 
                                            & {Household\\ Members} 
                                                    & Married 
                                                            &{Divorced/\\Seperated} 
                                                                    &Single & Widow & Age   & Obser\-vations  \\
    \midrule
Austria     & 0.39  & 0.027 & 0.56  & 0.33  & 2     & 0.62  & 0.1   & 0.18  & 0.1   & 48    & 2941 \\
Belgium     & 0.37  & 0.066 & 0.52  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.7   & 0.08  & 0.14  & 0.09  & 51    & 2785 \\
Bulgaria    & 0.23  & 0.003 & 0.53  & 0.44  & 3     & 0.72  & 0.07  & 0.11  & 0.11  & 50    & 2827 \\
Croatia     & 0.36  & 0.005 & 0.57  & 0.46  & 3     & 0.64  & 0.05  & 0.21  & 0.11  & 47    & 1931 \\
Cyprus      & 0.29  & 0.057 & 0.52  & 0.54  & 3     & 0.68  & 0.05  & 0.22  & 0.05  & 45    & 1465 \\
Czechia     & 0.36  & 0.005 & 0.57  & 0.43  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.12  & 0.14  & 0.08  & 45    & 2925 \\
Denmark     & 0.6   & 0.02  & 0.51  & 0.33  & 2     & 0.64  & 0.1   & 0.16  & 0.09  & 53    & 2878 \\
Estonia     & 0.41  & 0.006 & 0.61  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.55  & 0.12  & 0.18  & 0.15  & 51    & 2815 \\
Finland     & 0.42  & 0.019 & 0.55  & 0.26  & 2     & 0.57  & 0.13  & 0.17  & 0.13  & 54    & 2870 \\
France      & 0.38  & 0.059 & 0.55  & 0.39  & 2     & 0.6   & 0.12  & 0.19  & 0.09  & 50    & 2905 \\
Germany     & 0.35  & 0.027 & 0.51  & 0.32  & 2     & 0.66  & 0.07  & 0.19  & 0.07  & 51    & 4304 \\
Greece      & 0.25  & 0.016 & 0.52  & 0.4   & 3     & 0.62  & 0.07  & 0.24  & 0.08  & 47    & 2918 \\
Hungary     & 0.21  & 0.004 & 0.59  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.64  & 0.11  & 0.13  & 0.13  & 49    & 2842 \\
Ireland     & 0.37  & 0.09  & 0.55  & 0.49  & 3     & 0.73  & 0.04  & 0.18  & 0.06  & 47    & 2771 \\
Italy       & 0.32  & 0.01  & 0.56  & 0.51  & 3     & 0.71  & 0.05  & 0.18  & 0.06  & 47    & 2842 \\
Latvia      & 0.41  & 0.006 & 0.57  & 0.49  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.11  & 0.16  & 0.07  & 44    & 2714 \\
Lithuania   & 0.31  & 0.001 & 0.59  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.53  & 0.13  & 0.19  & 0.15  & 48    & 2866 \\
Luxembourg  & 0.48  & 0.379 & 0.56  & 0.54  & 3     & 0.69  & 0.09  & 0.15  & 0.07  & 48    & 1414 \\
Malta       & 0.28  & 0.023 & 0.6   & 0.48  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.04  & 0.2   & 0.09  & 52    & 1419 \\
Netherlands & 0.61  & 0.022 & 0.53  & 0.36  & 2     & 0.63  & 0.07  & 0.27  & 0.03  & 52    & 2864 \\
Poland      & 0.27  & 0.003 & 0.61  & 0.45  & 3     & 0.66  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.13  & 48    & 2793 \\
Portugal    & 0.21  & 0.016 & 0.56  & 0.42  & 3     & 0.62  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.12  & 49    & 2788 \\
Romania     & 0.2   & 0     & 0.5   & 0.42  & 3     & 0.73  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.1   & 47    & 2754 \\
Slovakia    & 0.3   & 0.008 & 0.58  & 0.5   & 3     & 0.69  & 0.07  & 0.14  & 0.11  & 48    & 2895 \\
Slovenia    & 0.34  & 0.012 & 0.57  & 0.46  & 3     & 0.67  & 0.04  & 0.17  & 0.11  & 51    & 2783 \\
Spain       & 0.29  & 0.06  & 0.52  & 0.44  & 3     & 0.68  & 0.06  & 0.19  & 0.07  & 48    & 2854 \\
Sweden      & 0.62  & 0.026 & 0.47  & 0.29  & 2     & 0.62  & 0.12  & 0.18  & 0.07  & 56    & 2890 \\
United Kingdom
            & 0.39  & 0.091 & 0.54  & 0.38  & 2     & 0.55  & 0.09  & 0.26  & 0.1   & 50    & 3710 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}\par
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thank you so much for your advice. I will try my best to put some effort into learning these preambles. Actually, I am really new to Latex. My professor shared his preambles with me. I am in a situation where I don't have much time to learn about Latex. I tried my best to figure it out, but I still met many problems and really need help. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I tried the code. But it only works in overleaf, not in the TeXShop. BTW, I really like your design!!

Comment: @Snow, TeXShop is editor as far as I know (I'm not familiar with it). Check, if your LaTeX installation contain `tabularray` package.  If not, install it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change long texts in each heading to something shorter like acronyms/symbols or rotate them. The table also has numbers formatted by `siunitx` and its `S` column-type. After suggested changes, including rotation, the table can fit a page without having to use the landscape environment.

You should sort out your preamble. At least, remove duplicates and redundant packages. Don't add everything you come across and keep only those packages you actually use in a document.

Here's he code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
% \usepackage[longnamesfirst,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{cancel}
% \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}
% \usepackage{graphicx} 
% \usepackage{indentfirst}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{plain}
% \usepackage{afterpage}
% \bibliographystyle{apsr}
% \usepackage{theorem}
% \usepackage{multirow,dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{chngcntr}
% \usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{makecell}
% \usepackage{float}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
% \usepackage[all]{nowidow}
% \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\tabnote}[1]{\vskip5pt{\justifying\noindent\small {\emph{Note:~}#1\par}}}
% \usepackage{epigraph}
% \usepackage{fullwidth}
% \usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
% \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont

\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setstretch{1.21}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}

% \DeclareMathOperator*{\rk}{rk}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Card}{Card}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{Prob}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\cov}{cov}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\var}{var}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var\,}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Post}{Post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Pre}{Pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\post}{post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\pre}{pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Mid}{Mid}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\MID}{MID}


\begin{document}
{%\begin{landscape}
  \small
  % Settings for makecell
  \renewcommand*\theadalign{l}
  \renewcommand*\theadfont{\normalfont\small}
  \renewcommand*\theadset{\setstretch{0.8}}
  % Setting chaption
  \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=0pt}
  % Spacing
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Add caption}
  \label{tab:addlabel}% 
  \begin{longtable}{
      l
      S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
      S[table-format=1.3,minimum-decimal-digits=3]
      *2{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      c
      *4{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      *2{c}
    }
    \toprule
    Country
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Heavy}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Foreigner}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Female}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Parental\\Status}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Household\\Members}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Married}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Divorced\\/Seperated}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Single}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Widow}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Age}}}
    & {\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Observations\enspace}}} \\
    \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    Austria        & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
    Belgium        & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
    Bulgaria       & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
    Croatia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
    Cyprus         & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
    Czechia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
    Denmark        & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
    Estonia        & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
    Finland        & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
    France         & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
    Germany        & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
    Greece         & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
    Hungary        & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
    Ireland        & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
    Italy          & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
    Latvia         & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
    Lithuania      & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
    Luxembourg     & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
    Malta          & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
    Netherlands    & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
    Poland         & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
    Portugal       & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
    Romania        & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
    Slovakia       & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
    Slovenia       & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
    Spain          & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
    Sweden         & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
    United Kingdom & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
    \end{longtable}
  }%\end{landscape}%
\end{document}
```

and the table

[image]

Edit. Table in a horizontal mode.

Here's the code for a horizontal table inside `landscape`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
% \usepackage[longnamesfirst,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{cancel}
% \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}
% \usepackage{graphicx} 
% \usepackage{indentfirst}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{plain}
% \usepackage{afterpage}
% \bibliographystyle{apsr}
% \usepackage{theorem}
% \usepackage{multirow,dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{chngcntr}
% \usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
% \usepackage{float}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
% \usepackage[all]{nowidow}
% \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\tabnote}[1]{\vskip5pt{\justifying\noindent\small {\emph{Note:~}#1\par}}}
% \usepackage{epigraph}
% \usepackage{fullwidth}
% \usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
% \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont

\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}}
\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}

% \DeclareMathOperator*{\rk}{rk}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Card}{Card}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{Prob}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\cov}{cov}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\var}{var}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var\,}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Post}{Post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Pre}{Pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\post}{post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\pre}{pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Mid}{Mid}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\MID}{MID}

% \setstretch{1.21}
\newcommand\thead[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \small
  % Setting chaption
  \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=-6pt}
  % Spacing
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Add caption}
  \label{tab:addlabel}% 
  \begin{longtable}{
      l
      S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
      S[table-format=1.3,minimum-decimal-digits=3]
      *2{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      c
      *4{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      *2{c}
    }
    \toprule
    Country
    & {\thead{Heavy}}
    & {\thead{Foreigner}}
    & {\thead{Female}}
    & {\thead{Parental\\Status}}
    & {\thead{Household\\Members}}
    & {\thead{Married}}
    & {\thead{Divorced/\\Seperated}}
    & {\thead{Single}}
    & {\thead{Widow}}
    & {\thead{Age}}
    & {\thead{Observations\enspace}} \\
    \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    Austria        & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
    Belgium        & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
    Bulgaria       & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
    Croatia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
    Cyprus         & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
    Czechia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
    Denmark        & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
    Estonia        & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
    Finland        & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
    France         & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
    Germany        & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
    Greece         & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
    Hungary        & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
    Ireland        & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
    Italy          & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
    Latvia         & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
    Lithuania      & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
    Luxembourg     & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
    Malta          & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
    Netherlands    & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
    Poland         & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
    Portugal       & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
    Romania        & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
    Slovakia       & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
    Slovenia       & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
    Spain          & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
    Sweden         & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
    United Kingdom & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can comment out one more package -- `mathtools` loads `amsmath`,

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Since I am writing a paper, can I have the titles that are not in the rotated format?  I am very new to Latex. I mainly use it to finish my thesis

Comment: @Snow Before I change titles, it seems [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671089/31283) has already an answer for you and I wouldn't like to end up with a copy of the existing solution. Is there something wrong with [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671089/31283)'s answer?

Comment: @Snow I edited my answer and added a table in horizontal mode. GL.

Comment: @Celdor It works! Thank you so much!!